# Finding the shortest distance of multiple paths using prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path, visual-prolog

I have this code and I want to compere the 3 distances and show the shortest on screen:

```
domains
node=symbol 
distance = integer 

PREDICATES 
nondeterm link(node, node, distance) 
nondeterm path(node, node, distance) 

CLAUSES 
link(a,b,4). 
link(a,c,2). 
link(b,g,5). 
link(c,g,6). 
link(c,d,5). 
link(d,g,3). 

path(S,D,TDist):- 
    link(S,D,TDist). 
path(S,D,TDist):- 
    link(S,X,TD1), path(X,D,TD2), TDist=TD1+TD2. 

GOAL 
path(a,g,TotalDistance).
```

How can I modify this code to get me the shortest distance?

Comment: Probably you want to use something like `setof/3` to get all the distances and the find the minimal one by sorting them by length. But Visual Prolog is seldom used these days so not many people are around who can help you with it. If you can switch to SWI, I would recommend it.

Comment: @DanielLyons is the syntax that different?

Comment: Given the weights are positive, you should implement *Dijkstra's algorithm*, or if not, *Bellman-Ford's algorithm*. By enumerating all paths, this can scale *exponentially* whereas *Dijkstra's algorithm* and *Bellman-Ford's algorithm* are polynomial.

Comment: It's different enough to be troublesome, and I don't have Windows to test against, or a Visual Prolog license. The majority of us seem to have our needs fulfilled by SWI or one of the other open-source implementations, most of which are also cross-platform.